# not all header values passed to lambda from android retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am passing couple of header values from Android Kotlin app using Retrofit. I receive 1 value (scenario) but other value (projectName) is 'undefined' in AWS lambda, event headers. Do you see any problem in my code?

If I set these headers in Postman and test then it works fine. So nothing wrong on Lambda side.

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response

class HeaderInterceptor: Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("projectName", "androidnextgen")
            .addHeader("scenario", "default")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

}
```

Postman:
[Headers from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gASRI.png)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the interceptor. How about the retrofit setup? Do you add the interceptor? Are you accidentally clearing `projectName`? If you check with an http proxy, can you see the header being sent? Last and possibly the most fringe one - http headers are case-insensitive to the best of my knowledge. Maybe the lambda is not handling this correctly? Maybe the header is received as `PROJECTNAME` and the lambda is using case-sensitive checks?

Comment: I don't remember what I did but I started receiving these values. I will post if I remember what I changed.